# Creating static home page for CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a CakePHP3 project. I want a `static homepage` that will be loaded on `www.mysite.com`.

For this I have created a `PagesController` which will handle all the static pages in the website like `about`,`contact`,etc.

I am having `display.ctp` view in `Template/Pages/display.ctp` to load on `www.mysite.com`.

But, for testing (routes are not configured yet), I'm using `www.mysite.com/pages` and `www.mysite.com/pages/display` to show the view but it gives error as

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysite.pages' doesn't exist
```

Do I need to create `Table` for this ?

Comment: No you do not have to cretae a table for your pages. You should have `$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);` in your routes.php

Comment: thanks. I also have to fetch data from some models to show on this static homepage. How it could be done

Comment: If you want to get data from models than use the corresponding controller, not a page

Comment: @anujsharma9196  use and include cells on homepage http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is much, much easier than that

> For this I have created a PagesController

There is already a [pages controller for serving static content](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Controller/PagesController.php#L38), and a
[static template for the home page](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Template/Pages/home.ctp), there is no need to create/overwrite the default pages controller, to replace it with the same (or less) functionality. This is also [mentioned in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html)

The steps to modify static pages (with default routes) are:

- edit `src/Template/Pages/home.ctp` - look at the url `/`
- create/edit `src/Template/Pages/something.ctp` - look at the url `/pages/something`

Comment: Thanks... This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the application is looking for a model named Page. To tell the application that your controller does not refer to any model you have to use something like bellow. Also add the proper action. www.mysite.com/pages/display means in controller "pages" call action "display".

```
class MyController extends AppController {
   var $uses = false;
   public function display {}
}
```